# Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'MyOrderTableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I would like to click the row based on ID,

So i've declare an array to store the IDs:

```
var idenArr = [String]()
```

On the didSelectRowAt indexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myOrderTableViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyOrderTableViewCell
        cell = idenArr[indexPath.row] `<-- Here show me this error "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'MyOrderTableViewCell'"`
}
```

Comment: || please read about table views.There are lot other problems in above 2 lines not just what you pointed.Why you need to deque a cell in didSelectRowAt that's the work of cellForRowAt? And you are assigning string value to type   MyOrderTableViewCelll.

Comment: In the error line, Your code is actually trying to assingn the value of id to the Cell. That is why it is coming.

Comment: change `cell =` to `cell.textLabel.text = `

Comment: Never call `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this, You can simply get it by:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let ID = idenArr[indexPath.row]
    print("Your selected Id is:" ID)
}
```